# Looking for App - Productivity measurement

Tags: software-rec

I'm looking for an application which logs my productivity, i.e. logging how long I've been working using LibreOffice, Firefox, or whatever.
My request is similar to this: https://productivity.stackexchange.com/questions/3803/time-tracking-software-to-measure-when-im-active-or-idle-on-my-computer-i-e

But unfortunately none of them works completely offline ( no data being sent to company XYZ) and is available for scientific linux.